# Como habilitar símbolos katex no latex renderizado via mathjax?

Tags: latex

Na empresa onde eu trabalho temos um time de produção de conteúdo que escreve todo conteúdo no Notion utilizando a funcionalidade de equations que eles disponibilizam. Para parsear esse conteúdo nós criamos [uma lib](https://github.com/asnunes/notion-page-to-html) que nos permite parsear esse conteúdo em html.

Esse conteúdo é renderizado pelo frontend usando a lib mathjax na versão 3.0.1. O problema é que o notion utiliza katex, enquanto o mathjax só renderiza latex. Logo, existem alguns símbolos (como por exemplo o \R para o símbolo do conjunto dos Reais) que não conseguem ser renderizados pelo mathjax. Eu chuto que exista algum plugin para habilitar a renderização desses simbolos mas realmente não consegui encontrar nada sobre.

[Aqui](https://www.respondeai.com.br/conteudo/algebra-linear-e-geometria-analitica/espacos-vetoriais-e-transformacoes-lineares/transformacao-linear/1025) um exemplo de página com problemas na renderização do símbolo dos reais

E abaixo o código de inicialização do Mathjax na nossa página

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.MathJax = {

    tex: {
      inlineMath: [
        [
          '$', '$'
        ],
        [
          '\\(', '\\)'
        ]
      ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    svg: {
      fontCache: 'global'
    },
    options: {
      renderActions: {
        addMenu: [0, '', ''] // Hide menu
      }
    },
    extensions: [
      "mml2jax.js", "tex2jax.js"
    ],
    showMathMenu: false,
    skipStartupTypeset: true,
    showProcessingMessages: false,
    messageStyle: "none",
    jax: ["input/MathML", "output/CommonHTML", "input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"]
  };
</script>

<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async="async" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
```